# Programm parallel QThread is creating a memory leak on application quit

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, qthread, visual-leak-detector

I have a bigger project, with a GUI and I want to manage some files in the background. I've implemented a new thread for this task and on runtime, everything works great. But as soon as I quit the application `visual-leak-detector` finds 3-7 memory leaks.

I separated my threading code and created a new project to check this with a minimal code example, but I'm still not able to fix my issue.

I think it has something to do with the event loop of the main program. Maybe the loop doesn't process the last events to delete my thread class and the thread itself. Because I stop and quit the thread in a destructor. But I'm not sure on this one.

Here is my minimal code:
threadclass.hpp:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class ThreadClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ThreadClass() {}
    virtual ~ThreadClass(){
        qDebug() << "ThreadClass Destructor";
    }

signals:
    // emit finished for event loop
    void finished();

public slots:
    // scan and index all files in lib folder
    void scanAll(){
        for(long i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            for (long k = 0; k < 1000000; k++);
            if(i%500 == 0)
                qDebug() << "thread: " << i;
        }
    }
    // finish event loop and terminate
    void stop(){
        // will be processed after scanall is finished
        qDebug() << "STOP SIGNAL --> EMIT FINSIHED";
        emit finished();
    }
};
```

threadhandler.hpp:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include "threadclass.hpp"

class ThreadHandler : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ThreadHandler(QObject *parent = 0) : parent(parent), my_thread(Q_NULLPTR) {}

    virtual ~ThreadHandler() {
        // TODO Check!
        // I think I don't have to delete the threads, because delete later
        // on finish signal. Maybe I just have to wait, but then how do I
        // check, if thread is not finished? Do I need to make a bool var again?

        if (my_thread != Q_NULLPTR && my_thread->isRunning())
        {
            emit stopThread();
            //my_thread->quit();
            my_thread->wait();
            //delete my_thread;
        }

        qDebug() << "ThreadHandler Destructor";
        my_thread->dumpObjectInfo();
    }

    void startThread(){
        if (my_thread == Q_NULLPTR)
        {
            my_thread = new QThread;
            ThreadClass *my_threaded_class = new ThreadClass();
            my_threaded_class->moveToThread(my_thread);

            // start and finish
            QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::started, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::scanAll);
            QObject::connect(this, &ThreadHandler::stopThread, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::stop);

            // finish cascade
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/21597042/6411540
            QObject::connect(my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::finished, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::deleteLater);
            QObject::connect(my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::destroyed, my_thread, &QThread::quit);
            QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::finished, my_thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

            my_thread->start();
        }
    }

signals:
    void stopThread();

private:
    QObject *parent;
    QThread* my_thread;
};
```

The main.cpp is crappy but seems to simulate the behavior of my main program well enough:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTime>
#include <QDebug>
#include "threadhandler.hpp"

#include <vld.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ThreadHandler *th = new ThreadHandler();
    th->startThread();

    // wait (main gui programm)
    QTime dieTime= QTime::currentTime().addSecs(5);
    while (QTime::currentTime() < dieTime) {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
    }

    qDebug() << "DELETE TH";
    delete th;
    qDebug() << "FINISH ALL EVENTS";
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 500);
    qDebug() << "QUIT";
    QCoreApplication::quit();
    qDebug() << "CLOSE APP";
    // pause console
    getchar();
//    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is the output from VLD:

```
WARNING: Visual Leak Detector detected memory leaks!
...
turns out this is very boring and uninteresting
...
Visual Leak Detector detected 3 memory leaks (228 bytes).
Largest number used: 608 bytes.
Total allocations: 608 bytes.
Visual Leak Detector is now exiting.
The program '[8708] SOMinimalExampleThreads.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

**Update 1:** I added `qDebug() << "ThreadClass Destructor";` to the destructor of the `ThreadClass` and my new output looks like this:

```
...
thread:  9996
thread:  9997
thread:  9998
thread:  9999
ThreadHandler Destructor
FINISH ALL EVENTS
CLOSE APP
```

Now it is clear that the destructor of my threaded class is never called and therefore lost in the void. But then why is this not working?

```
QObject::connect(my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::finished, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::deleteLater);
```

**Update 2:** I found one problem in ThreadHandler:

```
emit stopThread();
my_thread->quit(); // <-- stops the event loop and therefore no deletelater
my_thread->wait();
```

I removed `my_thread->quit()` and now the destructor of ThreadClass is called, but `my_thread->wait()` never finishes.

Comment: A leak at exit is not that big of a deal usually. The entire process is going away so the OS will reclaim all memory anyway.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I was not sure on that one, but nice to know. But I still would like to solve this issue. This shouldn't happen at all, I think.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it's true, but the leak can be dangerous if destructors not being called are in charge of things like flushing files or de-allocating a shared memory region

Comment: @cbuchart I know. That's why I said "usually".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem description:

When the destructor of `ThreadHandler` emits `stopThread` from the main thread, Qt invokes the connected slot (`&ThreadClass::stop`) by posting an event into the worker thread's event loop (aka, a queued connection). This means that the event loop of the worker's needs to be ready for receiving new events when this signal is emitted (since you are relying on it to perform proper clean-up). However, as you've already spotted, the call to `thread->quit()` might cause the event loop to quit earlier than desired (before the worker thread makes its way to call `ThreadClass::stop`, and hence the signal `ThreadClass::finished` is not emitted). You might want to examine the output of this minimal example that reproduces the behavior I am talking about:

```
#include <QtCore>

/// lives in a background thread, has a slot that receives an integer on which
/// some work needs to be done
struct WorkerObject : QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  using QObject::QObject;
  Q_SLOT void doWork(int x) {
    // heavy work in background thread
    QThread::msleep(100);
    qDebug() << "working with " << x << " ...";
  }
};

/// lives in the main thread, has a signal that should be connected to the
/// worker's doWork slot; to offload some work to the background thread
struct ControllerObject : QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  using QObject::QObject;
  Q_SIGNAL void sendWork(int x);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

  QThread thread;
  WorkerObject workerObj;
  workerObj.moveToThread(&thread);
  // quit application when worker thread finishes
  QObject::connect(&thread, &QThread::finished, &a, &QCoreApplication::quit);
  thread.start();

  ControllerObject controllerObj;
  QObject::connect(&controllerObj, &ControllerObject::sendWork, &workerObj,
                   &WorkerObject::doWork);

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    QThread::msleep(1);
    // call thread.quit() when i is equal to 10
    if (i == 10) {
      thread.quit();
    }
    controllerObj.sendWork(i);
  }
  return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

On my machine, Here is a possible output:

```
working with  0  ...
working with  1  ...
working with  2  ...
working with  3  ...
```

Notice that, despite the fact that `thread.quit()` is called on the tenth iteration from the main thread, the worker thread might not process all messages received before the exit call (and we get the value `3` as the last value processed by the worker).<sup>*</sup>

## Solution:

Actually, Qt provides a canonical to way to quit a worker thread and perform necessary clean-up, since the signal `QThread::finished` is handled in a [special way](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#finished):

> When this signal is emitted, the event loop has already stopped running. No more events will be processed in the thread, **except for deferred deletion events**. **This signal can be connected to QObject::deleteLater(), to free objects in that thread.**

This means that you can use `thread->quit()` (the same way you were doing), but you just need to add:

```
connect(my_thread, &QThread::finished, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::stop);
```

to your `startThread` and remove the unnecessary `emit stopThread();` from the destructor.

---

<sup>*</sup> I couldn't find any page in the documentation that explains this behavior in detail, so I provided this minimal example to explain what I am talking about.

Comment: But my actual thread is not simply one heavy function. I would like to add more functionality in the future, like a `QFileSystemWatcher`. The thread should only stop by closing the program. Therefore the thread is never "finished" and I need to tell him: stop now.

Comment: This is exactly what can be solved using the pattern described in my answer. You can schedule as many workers as you wish for deletion when the thread exits by connecting their `deleteLater` slot to the thread's `finished` signal. The approach is definitely not limited to one worker with  one heavy function.

Comment: Oh. Now I see, what you mean. I call `thread->quit()` which emits `my_thread::finished` which then calls `my_threaded_class::stop`. Seems pretty nice. But how does it work, if `my_threaded_class` isn't finished? Atm, I purposely block my event loop with all the work so the `stop` call will be processed last and when all work is done. Will the `my_thread` wait for the class to finish?

Comment: Tested and it works. It is definitely a better solution than mine. I'll update my answer with the new full code and accept your answer as the solution.

Comment: `my_thread` is guaranteed to call all slots connected to `QThread::finished` after breaking out of the event loop. you can (and I would say, you should)  call `thread->wait()` after the call to `thread->quit()` in the destructor of `ThreadHandler` to make the main thread wait for the background thread until it finishes all necessary clean-up

Comment: Yes, the `thread->wait()` after `thread->quit()`is necessary. Without it, I had again two mem leaks.

Comment: btw, nested event loops are better avoided in most cases. There are plenty of resources that can explain the reasons better than me :)

Comment: I added the solution to my main project and I had two mem leaks again. I reduced my code part by part and I found a solution: Add `QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 500);` after `delete (ThreadHandler)`. This is in the destructor of my `MainWindow` and it looks like the event loop isn't spinning anymore in this stage. I moved the `delete` command to the `aboutToQuit()` slot in my `MainWindow`, but still no solution. Is there a way, to `delete` the `ThreadHandler` with the event loop still running at the end of the application?

Comment: I found [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/72532/abouttoquit-signal-question) in the qt forums. Chris Kawa: "Ideally you would wait for all the other threads to finish before you quit the event loop in the main thread.
If you can't do that for some reason I would wait for other threads to finish in the `aboutToQuit()` handler and then call `processEvents()` manually to process anything these threads posted after you already quit the event loop."

Comment: I am sorry, I cannot follow your description, maybe you can open a follow up question with another minimal example? or just provide an external link to one here in the comments? Personally, I would stay away from hacks that involve calling `QApplication::processEvents` or spinning nested event loops (unless I am really really sure there is no other way around)

Comment: Yes, I'll open a follow-up question, but the minimal example would be not very small. So maybe it'll take a while. I'll post the link to the new question here.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the `my_thread->wait()` function, blocks the event loop and therefore the quit and `deleteLater` cascade is never finished. <s>I fixed this with another method of waiting for the finished thread:</s>

```
removed
```

Here is the newly implemented solution from Mike. It was pretty easy to implement, I only had to change the connection to `my_threaded_class::stop` in the `threadhandler` class.

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QThread>
#include "threadclass.hpp"

class ThreadHandler : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ThreadHandler(QObject *parent = 0) : parent(parent), my_thread(Q_NULLPTR) {}

    virtual ~ThreadHandler() {

        if (my_thread != Q_NULLPTR && my_thread->isRunning())
        {
            my_thread->quit();
            my_thread->wait();
        }

        qDebug() << "ThreadHandler Destructor";
    }

    void startThread(){
        if (my_thread == Q_NULLPTR)
        {
            my_thread = new QThread;
            ThreadClass *my_threaded_class = new ThreadClass();
            my_threaded_class->moveToThread(my_thread);

            // start and finish
            QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::started, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::scanAll);
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468408
            QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::finished, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::stop);

            // finish cascade
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/21597042/6411540
            QObject::connect(my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::finished, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::deleteLater);
            QObject::connect(my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::destroyed, my_thread, &QThread::quit);
            QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::finished, my_thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

            my_thread->start();
        }
    }

signals:
    void stopThread();

private:
    QObject *parent;
    QThread* my_thread;
};
```