# How to inform threads to close on application quit with main event loop still spinning

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

This is a follow-up question to: [QThread is creating a memory leak on application quit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468408).

Basically, the solution of my question included something like this the destructors:

```
virtual ~MainWindow() {
    delete th; // th = thread handler
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 500);
}

virtual ~ThreadHandler() {
    if (my_thread != Q_NULLPTR && my_thread->isRunning()) {
        my_thread->quit();
        my_thread->wait();
    }
    qDebug() << "ThreadHandler Destructor";
}
```

I don't like the "manual" event loop with `processEvents`, but without it, I have two memory leaks. Obviously, the main event loop isn't spinning anymore when the destructor of my `MainWindow` is called. So I moved the `delete th;` command to an `aboutToQuit()` slot in my `MainWindow`, but I still need the extra event loop at the end. If I had read the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) I would have known that the event loop stopped working just before this event.

> This signal is emitted when the application is about to quit the main
>   event loop, e.g. when the event loop level drops to zero. This may
>   happen either after a call to quit() from inside the application or
>   when the user shuts down the entire desktop session.

**Question:**
Is there a way, to delete the `ThreadHandler` with the event loop still running at the end of the application? I mean, is there a signal like: "please post everything I have to do before quitting my job now"-signal?

Or is there another solution to solve this? The thread should work in the background the whole time, and is never "finished". There are signals to the thread, to give it new work, but on completion, the thread will just idle and not finish. This is intended.

I found [this](https://forum.qt.io/post/355466) in the Qt forums. Chris Kawa:

> Ideally you would wait for all the other threads to finish before you
>   quit the event loop in the main thread. If you can't do that for some
>   reason I would wait for other threads to finish in the `aboutToQuit()`
>   handler and then call `processEvents()` manually to process anything
>   these threads posted after you already quit the event loop.

Is this still right and there is no better solution?

I have a [minimal, compilable, working example](https://github.com/Darkproduct/stackoverflow/tree/master/Questions/QtCloseThreadOnMainApplicationQuit) on git. It is a little bit too big to post, without cluttering everything with boring code.

Here is the key element: How do I setup the thread:

```
my_thread = new QThread;
ThreadClass *my_threaded_class = new ThreadClass();
my_threaded_class->moveToThread(my_thread);

// start and finish
QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::started, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::scanAll);
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53468408
QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::finished, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::stop);

// finish cascade
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/21597042/6411540
QObject::connect(my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::finished, my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::deleteLater);
QObject::connect(my_threaded_class, &ThreadClass::destroyed, my_thread, &QThread::quit);
QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::finished, my_thread, &QThread::deleteLater);

my_thread->start();
```

Comment: Just wondering, does this "memory leak" only occur on application shutdown? In that case, you don't really have a memory leak...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt If you have an object and you lost all reference to it, then you have a memory leak. It's simple.

Comment: It's not really that simple. Resources are automatically reclaimed on shutdown. Unless the amount of resources increases over the runtime of the program, you don't have a problem.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I know that this not a serious issue and will never cause any problems on systems that claim memory back, but it is a memory leak and bad coding style to leave it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're relying on the fact that the application is quitting to signal the background thread to quit, wait for it and then delete it. Why would you need deferred deletion in this case? I don't think that there is any reason to do so.

Since `ThreadHandler` is the class that creates, starts and ends your background thread, you should make it responsible to delete that thread too. Just add the following line in `ThreadHandler` destructor (after `my_thread->quit();` and `my_thread->wait()`):

```
delete my_thread;
```

This should be safe, as the thread is guaranteed to have stopped beforehand. Also, since you are destroying your `my_thread` instance from the destructor, you should now remove this line from `ThreadHandler::startThread()`:

```
QObject::connect(my_thread, &QThread::finished, my_thread, &QThread::deleteLater);
```

After that, you can go back to deleting your `ThreadHandler` instance from the `MainWindow`'s destructor (without any hacks that involve neither `aboutToQuit` nor `QApplication::processEvents`).

Comment: But then I'll lose `ThreadClass *my_threaded_class = new ThreadClass();` as memory leak. I can save this pointer too in my `ThreadHandler` class, but I'll most likely expand the thread and move several objects to this thread. Then I need to keep track of all pointers. I thought this handy signal cascade will do this for me. Unfortunately, the Thread has no way to delete all objects in the thread, I think.

Comment: why would you lose `my_thread_class`? this worker object is owned by the thread (since we have the `finished` signal from the thread connected to its `deleteLater` slot). The thread itself is owned by `thread_handler` which is owned by the `MainWindow` object. No need to keep track of owning pointers to worker objects manually if you want their lifetime to match that of the thread (just connect their `deleteLater` slot to the thread's `finished` signal)